# Labels of d3 chart cutting at edge

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts

I have created pie chart in d3.
Now when label of d3 pie is big then it will go out of chart container.

How to make sure if label is going out of edge container then word should be break and then next word will come in next line.
I have added text in pie chart below way.

```
var text = main.select('.labels').selectAll('text')
                .data(pie(options.data), key);

            text.enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr('x', function(d, i)
                {
                    centroid = arc.centroid(d);
                    midAngle = Math.atan2(centroid[1], centroid[0]);
                    x = Math.cos(midAngle) * (radius * 1.2);
                    sign = (x > 0) ? 1 : -1
                    labelX = x + (5 * sign)
                    return labelX;
                })
                .attr('y', function(d, i){
                    centroid = arc.centroid(d);
                    midAngle = Math.atan2(centroid[1], centroid[0]);
                    y = Math.sin(midAngle) * (radius * 1.2);
                    return y;
                })
                .style('text-anchor', function(d){
                    centroid = arc.centroid(d);
                    midAngle = Math.atan2(centroid[1], centroid[0]);
                    x = Math.cos(midAngle) * (radius * 1.2);
                    return (x > 0) ? "start" : "end";
                })
                .style('font-size', '13px')
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.data.name + ': ' + d.data.value + "( " + d3.round(100* d.value / total, 1) + "% " + ")";
                });
```

d.data.name is main text to show and other value is percentage in brackets.

This labels are going out of chart container when we have big label or when we have label which is near by some edge.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the next approach:

```
If (label.x) < (width/2)  =>> text-anchor: start
If (label.x) > (width/2)  =>> text-anchor: end
```

[image]

Hope this help